cannot access prisma enum type in interface file
I have a type enum with 3 values, and a type that have 3 specific partials with each value in this enum
this is enum in
prisma/schema.prisma
enum LayerType {
  TEXT
  IMAGE
  GROUP
}

this is my interface
import { LayerType } from "@prisma/client";

export type LayerBase = {
  title: string;
  description: string;
  title: string;
};

export type TextLayer = LayerBase & {
  text: string;
  type: LayerType.TEXT;
};
export type ImageLayer = LayerBase & {
  url: string;
  type: LayerType.IMAGE;
};
export type GroupLayer = LayerBase & {
  items: string[];
  type: LayerType.GROUP;
};

export type ContentLayer = TextLayer | ImageLayer | GroupLayer;

i can't using LayerType.TEXT | IMAGE or GROUP. I still can do it with normal enum in ts file
/interface.d.ts
enum LayerType {
  TEXT,
  IMAGE,
  GROUP,
}

my purpose is get correct type from ContentLayer that doesnt get type error like this

const getLayer = (layer: ContentLayer) => {
    let content = "";
    switch (layer.type) {
      case LayerType.GROUP:
        content = layer.items.join(",");
      case LayerType.IMAGE:
        content = layer.url;
      case LayerType.TEXT:
        content = layer.text;
    }

    return <div>{content}</div>;
  };


layer can cast type with as but i still wonder that is there anyway to keep it simple like this with using enum like enum in ts
